# Pandas groupby and assign last of first group to the first of second group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below:

```
def addJump(s):
    return s+'-'+s.shift(-1)

newDF = pd.DataFrame({
   'Group': ['A','A','B','C','B','B','A','C','C','A','D','D'],
   'Value': [1  , 3 , 5 , 10, 3 , 4 , 12, 11, 5 , 6 , 8 , 9 ],
   'Extra': [0  , 7 , 0 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 2 , 5 , 0 , 0 ]
}, index=   [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4])
newDF['Jump'] = newDF.groupby(level=0)['Group'].transform(addJump)
newDF

  Group  Value  Extra  Jump
0   A      1    0      A-A
0   A      3    7      A-B
0   B      5    0      NaN
1   C     10    3      C-B
1   B      3    0      B-B
1   B      4    0      NaN
2   A     12    1      A-C
2   C     11    0      NaN
3   C      5    2      C-A
3   A      6    5      A-D
3   D      8    0      NaN
4   D      9    0      NaN
```

I need to find within the same `index`, where the group changes and update `Value` of the first occurrence of the next `Group` to be the last `Value` of the previous `Group`. For example, if we look at index 0, `Value` in Row 3 Shall be updated to be the `Value[row 2] + Extra[row 2]=10` , and the update will be like follows.

```
  Group  Value  Extra  Jump
0   A      1    0      A-A
0   A      3    7      A-B
0   B      10   0      NaN
```

The final Result shall be as follows:

```
  Group  Value  Extra  Jump
0   A      1    0      A-A
0   A      3    7      A-B
0   B     10    0      NaN
1   C     10    3      C-B
1   B     13    0      B-B
1   B      4    0      NaN
2   A     12    1      A-C
2   C     12    0      NaN
3   C      5    2      C-A
3   A      7    5      A-D
3   D      12   0      NaN
4   D      9    0      NaN
```

I can use `groupby(level=0)` to work on each index group separately as done with addJump Function. However, I will need to again `groupby('Group')` and apply the next function where I call the last of the first `Group` and the assign it to the first of the second `Group`. And this is exactly where I struggle.

Comment: is your data ordered, all the same index are following?

Comment: Yes, they are ordered

Comment: for index =3 group D, original value in the previous row (index=3, group=A) gives 6+5=11, but you said the result is 12, is it because the value new value of the row (index=3, group=A) becomes 7 after the manipulation you wrote 12?

Comment: Yes Exactly as you stated. The new value is 7 so the updated value would be 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need the previous value updated in case it changes too, it is easier to write a for loop. Create a mask with True for the rows you want to change, then do a simple if else in a loop for

```
# create a mask to get True for rows meeting the criteria to change
mask = (newDF['Group'].ne(newDF['Group'].shift()) 
        & (newDF.index.to_series().shift() == newDF.index))

# initialize values and return list
newVal = newDF['Value'].iloc[0]
l = []

# now loop keep the value from the previous loop and extra coumn shifted
for val, ext_sh, b in zip(newDF['Value'], newDF['Extra'].shift(fill_value=0), mask):
    if b: # you change these rows
        newVal = newVal + ext_sh
    else: # keep original value
        newVal = val
    l.append(newVal)
# assign the result to a column, can do it in Value directly
newDF['newVal'] = l

print(newDF)
  Group  Value  Extra  newVal
0     A      1      0       1
0     A      3      7       3
0     B      5      0      10
1     C     10      3      10
1     B      3      0      13
1     B      4      0       4
2     A     12      1      12
2     C     11      0      13
3     C      5      2       5
3     A      6      5       7
3     D      8      0      12
4     D      9      0       9
```

**EDIT**: after looking a bit, you can have a vectotize version of it, using the `mask_` with True for the rows to change, then propagate previous values once `mask` the `mask_`, and add the extra values shifted and cumulative sum for the wanted rows, remove to restart the cumulative sum when not in `mask_`. honestly it is harder to maintain that the version with for loop, but probably faster

```
mask_ = (newDF['Group'].ne(newDF['Group'].shift()) 
        & (newDF.index.to_series().shift() == newDF.index))

s_ = newDF['Extra'].shift().where(mask_).cumsum().ffill().fillna(0)

newDF['newVal2'] = (
    newDF['Value'].mask(mask_).ffill()
    + s_ 
    - s_.mask(mask_).ffill()
)
```

Comment: That works for the example I have shared. But is there a faster way? As the original Dataframe I have contains 200k+ rows and that would take a long time.

Comment: @AliSultan see the Edit, I found a vectorize way, but harder to understand it :)

Comment: Will you be able to comment on the lines for me to understand better? As you said the second solution is a bit tricky

Comment: @AliSultan it is a actually pretty hard to put meaningful words on the operation, I would suggest to `print(s_)`, `print(s_.mask(mask_).ffill())` and `print(s_- s_.mask(mask_).ffill())` to see the result. really it is used to get a cumulative sum of extra when several following rows have to change, see the last not 0 of the last print is 7, that is the Extra of the previous row (5) + the one of the row again before (2). because finally, using the previous updated value is like using the value two rows before (5) + extra of two row before (2) + extra row before (5)